# как вывести пути, обходимые методом getResource()

Tags: java

Как мне вывести пути, по которым пройдутся методы `class.getResource()`, `class.getClassLoader().getResource()` в поисках ресурсов. Для некоторого класса.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам просто нужно понять какие каталоги и библиотеки включены в classpath, то можно использовать [`URLClassLoader.getURLs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#getURLs%28%29)

```
public static URL[] getClasspath(Class<?> clazz) {
    ClassLoader cl = clazz.getClassLoader();
    return ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
}
```

Это не выведет вам полное дерево содержимого каждого ресурса, для этого его придется рекурсивно обойти вручную. Например, таким образом можно получить содержимое каталога:

```
Enumeration<URL> en = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResources("org.package.name");
if ( en.hasMoreElements() ) {
    URL url = en.nextElement();
    File file = new File(url.toURI());
    String[] filenames = file.list();
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(filenames));
}
```

Также за образец можно взять реализацию в Spring - [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java)

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что class.getClassLoader().getResource(). будет искать ресурсы по путям, которые мне напечатает ваш кпервый код выше ?